# What are the primes in quadratic integer ring $\mathbb{Z}[D]$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

Is it possible to classify all the primes in the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[D]\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$? If not, are there additional assumptions on $d$ like residue mod 4 or the "class number" of $\mathbb{Z}[D]$ that make it possible?

I am also interested in whether $\mathbb{Z}[D]$ always has units other than $\pm 1$. I know that the units are precisely those of unit norm, i.e. the solutions to $a^2-D^2b^2 = \pm 1$.

(I know this question and ones similar to it have been asked before, but I couldn't find a good answer.)

Comment: What is $D$ w.r.t.  $d$?

Comment: $D=\sqrt{d}$ if $D\equiv 2,3\mod 4$ and $D$ is $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ if $d\equiv 1\mod 4.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $\mathbf Z[D]$  is *above* a prime $p\in \mathbf Z$, i.e. $\mathfrak p\cap \mathbf Z=p\mathbf Z$.

Now for a given odd prime $p$,

- either $p$ is *inert*, i.e. $p\mathbf Z[D]$ is a prime ideal. It is the case if $d$ is not a square mod.  $p$,
- or $p$ is *decomposed*,  i.e. there exist two prime ideals  $\mathfrak p_1$ and  $\mathfrak p_2$ in $\mathbf Z[D]$, such that $p\mathbf Z[D]=\mathfrak p_1\cap\mathfrak p_2$. It is the case if $d$ is a (non-zero) square mod. $p$
- or $p$ is *ramified*, i.e. there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ such that $p\mathbf Z[D]=\mathfrak p^2$. It is the case if $d$ is a multiple of $p$.

$2$ is inert if $d\equiv 5\mod8$, decomposed if $d\equiv 1\mod8$, ramified otherwise.

As to the group of units, it is a finite group if $d<0$, and more precisely it has order $4$ for the ring of Gaussian integers ($d=-1$), $6$ for the group of Eisenstein integers ($d=-3$), $2$ otherwise.

If $d>0$, the group of units is isomorphice to the product of the group $\{\pm1\}$ and a monogeneous group (i. e. t is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z$).

*Dirichlet's unit theorem* describes the structure of the ring of integers of any algebraic number field.

Comment: Also, quadratic reciprocity tells which primes will split.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.